# how to pass string value in `find_by_sql`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, find-by-sql

Using query like:

`Campaign.find_by_sql("select c.*,sc.*,org.name as org_name from campaigns as c left join super_campaigns as sc ON sc.id= c.super_campaign_id left join organisations as org ON org.id= c.organisation_id where c.status=0 AND sc.status='active'")`

Getting error after using `sc.status='active'`.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using interpolation, here is an example from a project i made for doing something similar

```
self.find_by_sql("SELECT s.subject_title  AS subject_name,s.subject_code AS subject_code,
COUNT(*) AS total_complaints,
COUNT(CASE p.priority_name WHEN '#{Ticket::HIGH}'        THEN 1 END) AS high_complaints,
COUNT(CASE p.priority_name WHEN '#{Ticket::NORMAL}' THEN 1 END) AS normal_complaints,
COUNT(CASE p.priority_name WHEN '#{Ticket::LOW}'     THEN 1 END) AS low_complaints
FROM
tickets AS t
JOIN
subjects AS s
ON  t.subject_id = s.id
JOIN
priorities AS p
ON t.priority_id = p.id
WHERE
p.priority_name IN ('#{Ticket::HIGH}', '#{Ticket::NORMAL}', '#{Ticket::LOW}')
GROUP BY s.subject_title, s.subject_code
ORDER BY total_complaints ASC")
```

As you can see `#{Ticket::HIGH}` is coming from `PRIORITY = [HIGH = 'high', NORMAL = 'normal', LOW = 'low']` same goes for the others

Note: this is a part of the original code.